# Using AWS CloudHSM on EC2 Github Runner

Tags: amazon-ec2, github-actions, gitlab-ci-runner, amazon-cloudhsm

I have a Windows EC2 instance that is configured correctly to use CloudHSM. We can use signtool.exe on this machine without issue. I am now trying to automate some of our signing process with a github action. The machine is configured correctly as a github runner and everything works fine until the signing step when I get this error.

```
n3fips_password env variable not set>
n3fips_password env variable not set>
SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.


The following certificates were considered:
Cfm2Shutdown: Application is not initialized 
Cfm2Shutdown: Application is not initialized 
    Issued to: My Company

    Issued by: DigiCert EV Code Signing CA (SHA2)

    Expires:   Date 

    SHA1 hash: My Certificates Hash


After EKU filter, 1 certs were left.
After expiry filter, 1 certs were left.
After Hash filter, 1 certs were left.
After Private Key filter, 0 certs were left.
```